# Fabric - Unable to Download: APP_NAME could not be installed at this time

Tags: xcode8, crashlytics, crashlytics-beta, xcode8.2

I'm using **Fabric/Crashlytics** to deploy the app for Beta Testers. Everything had been working fine for weeks, but for one build the following error message shows up when tester is trying to install the app:

> Unable to Download: APP_NAME could not be installed at this time [Done/Retry options]

[image]

Troubleshooting done so far:

- Deleting all cached provisioning files, deleting them from Dev account and creating fresh ones (all valid)
- Double-check that device UUID is on provisioning profile
- Double-check ad hoc distribuition profile is used (not developer provisioning profile)
- Deleting and reinstalling Crashlytics profile on the device
- Double-checking that all Capabilities are included on provisioning files
- Complete clean on Xcode project, including delete of all DerivedData
- Double-check there's enough free storage on the device

Additional info:

- No tester is able to install this build (including iOS 10.2)
- Bitcode was already = No
- Previous version had been deleted from device before new installing attempt
- Testers can install previous builds from Fabric. So the issue seems to be linked to this specific build
- I'm on Xcode 8.2, with iOS 9.0 deployment target

Any suggestions for further troubleshooting?

Comment: Facing the same issue. Any idea how could I fix it? I am not using the framework you mentioned below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it!

> **TL;DR: issue was caused by conflict with a Pod I had manually added a week ago**

This issue had nothing to do with Fabric / Crashlytics itself. It was caused by a framework (https://github.com/stone-pagamentos/sdk-ios-v2) I had manually added a week ago. It was somehow causing some conflict that would not allow the app to be installed on the device. no matter if it was distributed via Fabric or not.

After removing all the references for this Framework on Xcode, testers could successfully download and install the app with Fabric.

Comment: By the way, the pod that I recently added was Google Analytics. Mine works when the ad-hoc build is installed via itunes but not on Fabric Beta.

Comment: Nevermind. I got it working. It was indeed path issues on Library Search Paths. I had a Linker warning that only showed up when using a release build. To those having issues, try changing your scheme to "release" build then start debugging.